Unable to create view from models, created from complex JSON classes
This is my string in index method. I am trying to convert my JSON string to object of MultipleClasses and want to display in my view. But unable to do that.
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    MultipleClasses GetData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultipleClasses>(data);
    return View(GetData );
}

This is ViewModel Class
using ExternalAPIModule.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace ExternalAPIModule.ViewModel
{
    public class MultipleClasses
    {
        public User? User;
        public List<Users>? products { get; set; }
        public List<variant>? variants;

    }
}

This is my Model class (Copying as it is)
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//using static ExternalAPIModule.Models.User.Users;
using static ExternalAPIModule.Models.User;

namespace ExternalAPIModule.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public Users[] products { get; set; }
    }
    public class Users
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public double? id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("vendor")]
        public string? vendor { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string? title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public string? created_at { get; set; }
        public string? body_html { get; set; }
        public variant[] variants { get; set; }
        
    }
    public class variant
    {
        public string? price { get; set; }
        public string? compare_at_price { get; set; }

    }

}

How can I display the model in View to show JSON data? I want to convert the JSON to my view using ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC.
Currently I am trying to use this view that is giving error:
@model IEnumerable<ExternalAPIModule.ViewModel.MultipleClasses>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products.id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products.vendor)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products.title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products.created_at)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products.body_html)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.variant.price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.variant.compare_at_price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.products.id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.products.vendor)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.products.title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.products.created_at)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.products.body_html)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.variant.price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.variant.compare_at_price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>




How can I display the model in View to show JSON data?? I want to
convert the JSon to my view using ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

According to your shared code snippet, you have few inconsistencies within your current implementation.
First of all, your domain model and viewModel has mismatched type. You are using the IEnumerable<MultipleClasses> as the model in your view, but MultipleClasses is not an enumerable type. Instead, MultipleClasses is a single object containing lists. Also, its lacking of getter and setter as well.
Another issue is, the properties in the view are accessed incorrectly. For example, @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products.id) assumes products is a single object, not a list.
Apart from that, while you map our jsonProperty within your ViewModel, you should mind the naming convension and typos. Because, property names should be consistent in your models and view models. For example, products should be Products, and variant should be Variants.
In order to properly display the JSON data in your view using the MultipleClasses ViewModel, there are a few adjustments you need to make in your View and ViewModel.
Let's have a look in practice, how we can achieve that.
ViewModel:
public class MultipleClasses
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Users> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> Variants { get; set; }
}

Model:
public class User
{
    public Users[] Products { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public double? Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public string BodyHtml { get; set; }

    public Variant[] Variants { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string CompareAtPrice { get; set; }
}

Controller:
public class ComplexJsonToViewController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Dummy JSON data
        string data = @"
        {
            'User': null,
            'Products': [
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'vendor': 'Vendor1',
                    'title': 'Product1',
                    'created_at': '2021-01-01',
                    'body_html': 'Product 1 description',
                    'variants': [
                        {
                            'price': '10.00',
                            'compare_at_price': '15.00'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id': 2,
                    'vendor': 'Vendor2',
                    'title': 'Product2',
                    'created_at': '2021-02-01',
                    'body_html': 'Product 2 description',
                    'variants': [
                        {
                            'price': '20.00',
                            'compare_at_price': '25.00'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            'Variants': []
        }";

        MultipleClasses getData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultipleClasses>(data);
        return View(getData);
    }
}

View:
@model MultipleClasses

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.FirstOrDefault().Id)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.FirstOrDefault().Vendor)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.FirstOrDefault().Title)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.FirstOrDefault().CreatedAt)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.FirstOrDefault().BodyHtml)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Variants.FirstOrDefault().Price)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Variants.FirstOrDefault().CompareAtPrice)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Vendor)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Title)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.CreatedAt)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.BodyHtml)</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var variant in product.Variants)
                    {
                        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => variant.Price)</div>
                        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => variant.CompareAtPrice)</div>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = product.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = product.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = product.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Output:

Note: For the sake of this demonstration, I have used sample json data, you would call the API to fetch data.
